# Rails and ancestry - form submits 'parent_id' empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I've followed Railscast [episode #262](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) tutorial on ancestry. But when I submit my form, the rails server log says that `parent_id` is empty:

`rails server` log:

```
Started POST "/posts/1/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-26 16:14:59 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9+9U/etsazbrJxwWah/eRD9v3fKBnjpy+y5s+g7N/Bw=", "comment"=>{"parent_id"=>"", "author"=>"some name", "author_email"=>"mail@domain.com", "author_url"=>"", "content"=>"banane"}, "commit"=>"Post Comment", "post_id"=>"1"}
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("author", "author_email", "author_url", "content", "created_at", "post_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["author", "some name"], ["author_email", "mail@domain.com"], ["author_url", ""], ["content", "banane"], ["created_at", Thu, 26 Sep 2013 14:14:59 UTC +00:00], ["post_id", 1], ["updated_at", Thu, 26 Sep 2013 14:14:59 UTC +00:00]]
   (38.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/1
Completed 302 Found in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 39.4ms)
```

`comments_controller.rb`:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comment.parent_id=params[:parent_id]
end

def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:author, :author_email, :author_url, :content, :parent_id))

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      stuff
    else
      other stuff
    end
  end
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(...some stuff..., :parent_id)
end
```

`comment.rb`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_ancestry
end
```

`post.rb`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

`views/posts/show.html.erb`:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= show some stuff %>
  <%= link_to (post_path(:anchor => "respond", :parent_id => comment)) do%>
    <%= "Reply"%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= render 'comments/comment_form'%>
```

`_comment_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], html: { :id => "commentform"} do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
<%= some fields %>
<%= f.submit "Post Comment"%>
```

Rails debug info:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
parent_id: '17'
action: show
controller: posts
id: '1'
```

I guess somethings wrong with my create method in the `CommentsController`, but I can't figure out what's missing. So, I got this working. I was submitting the form from my posts/show view, so I had to call `@comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])` in the show action of the post-controller as well.

Comment: this line seems a little weird - what is the `comment` variable here?  `<%= link_to (post_path(:anchor => "respond", :parent_id => comment)) do%>`

Comment: I added some lines to the views/posts/show.html.erb. I think the link works fine: "0.0.0.0:3000/posts/1?parent_id=18#respond"  i see a different id for different comments

Comment: How do you get params[:parent_id] in your new action? It seems this is not being set properly.

Comment: the new action in the comment_controller is from the tutorial. actually the tutorial says "@message = Message.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])" and someone in the comments wrote the version I use. I get the same results either way. The new action in the post_controller is just "@post = Post.new".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails >3.0.0 try this in your comments controller:

```
@comment = Comment.new
@comment.parent_id=params[:parent_id]
```

instead of

```
@comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `:parent_id` to `comment_params` in the comments controller.